# In what NuGet package can I find Unity Localization namespaces?

Tags: unity-game-engine, nuget

I'm trying to build a stand-alone reusable C# library for UnityEngine and I'm having a little trouble. I have installed the UnityTechnologies.UnityEngine NuGet package which creates references to the UnityEditor and UnityEngine assemblies but Visual Studio is telling me that the UnityEditor.Localization.Settings namespace doesn't exist. UnityEditor.Localization and UnityEditor.Localization.Editor are there but none of the others (and there are quite a few).
So...where do I find that namespace? Based on the following Url, it exists: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.4/api/UnityEngine.Localization.Settings.html

Am I missing something in the documentation?

Comment: In none .. [Localization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.localization@1.4/manual/index.html) is a **Unity package** not NuGet ... You usually get it via the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-ui.html)

Comment: `I'm trying to build a stand-alone reusable C# library` .. so what is it standalone or UnityEngine? You probably want to refer to [Creating custom packages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html)

Comment: @derHugo - perhaps I should have left off "stand-alone" in the OP. I guess the important thing is that it's not tied to a specific Unity game/app.
Are you saying that I can't get access to Localization inside a custom .NET library? That I will have to build a custom Unity package, instead?

Comment: if your library is anyway supposed to be used in Unity context => There is no need to make this a general c# library => yes, make it a Unity package people can just add a dependency to. Or you might want to make it a paid asset for the [Asset store](https://assetstore.unity.com) in the end basically an [Asset Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetPackages.html) which has a bit less restrictions regarding format but no dependency handling - its basically kind of a smart Zip archive